# How to change Sun strength/specular/angle value via python without using nodes?

Tags: python, scripting, light

I found `bpy.types.SunLight(Light)`, but I don't know how to use it.

Can someone explain please?

I need to change some of the Sun's settings (strength/specular/angle) with python

Not a duplicate of how to GET a lamp, as this is a completely different question

[image]

Comment: Even this is a different question, you should post your first attempt (some code) at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the lights either through `bpy.data.lights` where all lights of the .blend file can be found or `bpy.context.scene.objects` which contains all objects in the current scene, including lights. For the latter you need to access `.data` for the light settings.

If you have a light called `Sun` in the current scene you could use either one of the approaches to modify the properties, as shown in the following example.

```
import bpy
import math

sun = bpy.data.lights["Sun"]
#sun = bpy.context.scene.objects["Sun"].data

sun.color = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
sun.energy = 5.0
sun.specular_factor = 0.5
sun.angle = math.pi * 10.0 / 180.0  # In radians
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! @rjg

Comment: One little question, how do I rotate sun?

Comment: I've tried it says ```AttributeError: 'SunLight' object has no attribute 'rotation_euler'```

Comment: Right. Use `bpy.context.scene.objects["Sun"]` to get the object and set the rotation with `bpy.context.scene.objects["Sun"].rotation_euler`

Comment: Yup, thanks a lot!!! @rjg